# Apache: help understand Action and AddHandler directives

Tags: apache2, cgi, addhandler

I'm trying to puzzle out Apache handlers. The [official documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/handler.html#examples) has the following example:

> The following directives will cause requests for files with the html extension to trigger the launch of the footer.pl CGI script.

```
Action add-footer /cgi-bin/footer.pl
AddHandler add-footer .html
```

> Then the CGI script is responsible for sending the originally requested document (pointed to by the PATH_TRANSLATED environment variable) and making whatever modifications or additions are desired.

I try to follow this example. My directory set up is:

- /var/www/testsite/index.html
- /var/www/testsite/cgi-bin/rp.sh

My virtual host file is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerName http://localhost-testsite
       DocumentRoot /var/www/testsite
       <Directory /var/www/testsite>
               Action footer /cgi-bin/rp.sh
               AddHandler footer .html
       </Directory>
       ErrorLog /var/www/logs/error-testsite.log
</VirtualHost>
```

If I understood the documentation correctly, when an html file is requested, my rp.sh script should be called with PATH_TRANSLATED variable set to the html file name. However, when I open localhost-testsite/index.html in my browser, I get an unexpected error:

```
[Thu Mar 14 15:38:18 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /var/www/testsite/cgi-bin/rp.sh/index.html
```

Am  I missing something? The most important question is: how can I make a cgi script process all files with a certain extension?

Apache version is Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu). All files and dirs have 777 permission.

Comment: I think the problem is that you also have to configure rp.sh to be a valid CGI script, although I'm not sure.  Make sure that you have `ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/testsite/cgi-bin/` in your Apache configuration.